# Unable to get user specific 'notes'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I have made a notes website(using MERN), where user can login and save notes.
When I tested it on my localhost mongodb compass, it worked fine. It showed the user specific notes.

But when I deployed it on heroku & used the mongodb atlas, its showing all the notes, of all the user(whoever logins, sees all the notes).

Also when deployed on heroku, if a user saves a note, it doesn't show after the user logins back(its still there in database).

Here's the code to fetch the notes user specific:

[image: Code to fetch user specific notes]

Any help would really be appreciated!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried adding `console.log(req.user.id)` and ensured the ID is present after user has added a note?

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Yes the ID is present. It all works fine in my localhost mongoDB, but after deploying on heroku and in mongoDB atlas, it has errors